# Regex in Python does not mach string (but it does when checking on rubular)

Tags: python, regex

I'm writing a program in Python that uses regular expressions. I am having trouble because an expression that I think should match a string doesn't do it.  This is the python code that reproduces my problem:

```
regex = re.compile(r"ord(er)? *0?([1-4])", re.I)
m = regex.match("CMord01")
```

m evaluates to FALSE.
I would very much like to find out why.
I've checked on http://rubular.com/ and there the expression does match the string as expected.
Thank you!

Comment: Use `regex.search()` instead of `regex.match()`. See [`search() vs. match()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match) in the Python docs.

Comment: Here in you expresion, the start of the string should be ord. It doesn't include *CM*. You probably want to prepend `.*` to your regexp.

Comment: @MarekKowalski that would obviously work but then all those junk characters are returned as part of the match. Depending on what they plan to do with the match, this might make things dirty/complicated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Python `re.match()` matches from the beginning of the string. The first letter in `CMord01` is `C`, not `O`, thus it does not match.

Most language's regular expression modules don't have this limitation so they match the string no problem. To have this kind of behaviour in Python you need to use `re.search()` instead. See ["search() vs. match()"](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match) for more information on the difference between the two functions.

Comment: Cheers, problem solved! Wasn't aware of search() vs match(), now I know.

Comment: @Guio It's an idiosyncrasy of Python. I remember I had to exact same problem.